# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils'

Tags: python, scripting

I was running a python script in Blender 2.82 for Manjaro and got this error:

```
Read prefs: /home/manjaro/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
found bundled python: /home/manjaro/Descargas/blender-2.82-e0cd5b980fc5-linux-glibc217-x86_64/2.82/python
Read blend: /home/manjaro/Descargas/blender-2.82-e0cd5b980fc5-linux-glibc217-x86_64/carpeta trabajo blender 2.82/vincent_modify/Vincent to be modify6b81.blend
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[1]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[1]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[2]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[3]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[2]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[1]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[1]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_R"].rotation_quaternion[3]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[2]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[2]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_low_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[3]
ERROR (bke.anim_sys): /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/anim_sys.c:4160 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["lip_up_4_bbone_easeout_L"].rotation_quaternion[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manjaro/Descargas/blender-2.82-e0cd5b980fc5-linux-glibc217-x86_64/carpeta trabajo blender 2.82/vincent_modify/Vincent to be modify6b81.blend/OpenCVAnimOperator", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils'
```

To be honest,I don't know how to fix it or what it means. The first thing that caught my attention was the "no module named 'imutils'" but it is installed...
I tried:

```
pip3 install imutil
```

and got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: imutils in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.5.3)
```

I also tried:

```
sudo pip3 install imutil
```

And got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/manjaro/.local/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
from pip._internal.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.main'
```

And here is where I'm stuck. So if anybody can help me...

Answer (score 0):

okay, my first post in blender....

go to directory. (i think you are using 2.82, i am using 2.81)

```
cd /home/manjaro/Descargas/blender-2.82-e0cd5b980fc5-linux-glibc217-x86_64/2.82/python/bin

./python3.7m -m ensure pip

./python3.7m -m ensurepip

./python3.7m -m pip install --upgrade pip --user

./python3.7m -m pip install opencv-contrib-python numpy --user
```

thats all i did and i hope your problem should get solve too.

br..
Yaju